# Error in Tabonuco-Yagrumo-Hybrid Netlogo model?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling, systemdynamics

I am working through how Netlogo's Tabonuco-Yagrumo-Hybrid model (http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/TabonucoYagrumoHybrid) integrates system dynamics and agent-based modelling. As I understand it, the model replaces the traditional 'flows' in a system dynamics model with an agent-based procedure, which is pretty cool.

However, in the Tabonuco-Yagrumo-Hybrid model, I am confused at the use of the reporters `agent-yagrumo-growth` and `agent-tabonuco-growth`.

The `agent-go` procedure sets the respective tree growth flows as:

```
to agent-go
  set yagrumo-growth agent-yagrumo-growth yagrumo-stock
  set tabonuco-growth agent-tabonuco-growth tabonuco-stock
...
end
```

As can be seen, the flows `yagrumo-growth` and `tabonuco-growth` are set using the reporters mentioned above, which take as input the current 'stock' values, i.e. the number of yagrumo and tabonuco trees, respectively. This makes sense.

Going to the definition of the reporter procedures, however, the current stock does not seem to be used at all in the calculations. To take the `agent-yagrumo-growth` procedure as an example:

```
to-report agent-tabonuco-growth [ current ]
  let total-grown 0
  let growable tabonucos with [ not all? neighbors [ any? turtles-here ] ]
    ask n-of ( count growable * tabonuco-growth-rate ) growable
    [ let seedpatch one-of neighbors with [ not any? turtles-here ]
      if ( seedpatch != nobody )
        [ ask seedpatch
            [ sprout-tabonucos 1 [ set color sky ]
              set total-grown total-grown + 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
    report total-grown
end
```

Why doesn't this reporter use the value given for `current`, which represents the current stock value. Am I missing something or is this an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Your analysis of the code you posted is correct.  Generally this would suggest conceptual error somewhere, although this code may still report the correct value (since it computes `growable`).  I suspect the code was refactored without bothering to remove the input parameter for this reporter.